# Windows azure custom domain mapping

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, cname

To bring an external domain to azure web app ,

- I configured CNAME FOR www,
- Configured cname for awverify ,
- added another CNAME to redirect root (example.com ) to www.example.com.

everything propagated properly

Then in azure portal i added these external domains , after a few tries everything worked fantastic, The link redirected to the azure portal.

but than i put http://example.com in the browser and it gives error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

May be i am missing something here. now what is required to be done ?

here are the CNAME entries added by me

- www.example.com      exmple.azurewebsites.net        Active
- awverify.www.example.com     awverify.example.azurewebsites.net      Active
- *.example.com        www.example.com     Active

What should be the entries in CNAME or A record ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you didn't configure the A record.  It is necessary it you want to use the naked domain.

Take a look a this Azure documentation page that explains in details how to set a domain name for your Web app: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

Comment: Thanks for comment, I did figure it out .